# Constructor not firing

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I'm probably missing some thing obvious but the constructor is not firing with new object. I've been pulling my hair out for hours. I did check I am getting results from the query.
The beginning of the class

```
class OrderDetail {
private $id;
private $product;
private $quanity;
private $price;
private $orderID;
private $noProduction;
private $productName;

public function _construct($orderID, $id = NULL, $product = NULL, $productName = NULL, $quanity = NULL, $price = NULL, $noProduction = NULL){
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->orderID = $orderID;
    echo "check";
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productName=$productName;
    $this->quanity = $quanity;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->noProduction = $noProduction;

}
```

The function that should create a new object

```
public static function getOrderDetails($orderID){
    $db=  database_connection::getDB();

    $query = "SELECT tblorder_details.*, tblproduct.product_name
              FROM tblorder_details INNER JOIN tblproduct ON tblorder_details.product_ID = tblproduct.product_ID
              WHERE (((tblorder_details.order_ID)= :orderID))";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':orderID', $orderID);
    $statement->execute();

    $orderDetails = array();
    foreach ($statement as $row){
        //echo $row["order_ID"];
        $orderDetail = new OrderDetail(
                                    $row["order_ID"],
                                    $row["order_details_ID"],
                                    $row["product_ID"],
                                    $row["product_name"],
                                    $row["quanity"],
                                    $row["price"],
                                    $row["no_production"]);

        $orderDetails[]=$orderDetail;
    }
    return $orderDetails;
}
```

Comment: you have to delete lines, till you get to the bare essence of the problem. you could reproduce the same problem with 3 lines, and that point it should become obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function __construct
```

You need two __

Comment: This is me slapping my forehead hard *smack*. Thanks a ton, I can't believe I've been staring at it this long and missed it.